# Android - Custom ListView Adapter - Multi Selection remove - Indexoutofbounds - why?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom Listview using a adapter class to extend ArrayAdapter of a Item class.  I have the ability to change between choice modes of NONE,Single and Multi.  This all works fine.  What I am trying to implement now is a method to removes items from the list view (and adapter) with multiple selection when in the multi choice mode.  However I get IndexOutOFBounds Exceptions when doing either of the following;
1) remove last item in listview in SINGLE choice mode (Note: anything before last item remove ok)
2) In multi selection choice mode I once again can not remove last item
3) again in multi selection mode I can remove single selected items before last item but 2 or more selections result in index out of bounds errors again.

I added debug log to show position being removed and size of getCheckItemPositions() and my for loop counter (e.g. i) and finally the item title of the item being removed.  If I comment out the actual listadpter.remove(position) line then the log output seems to indicator all is working fine  So I am now suspecting the issue falls into my adapter class getView method.  But my brain is exhausted and I am stuck.

MainActivity.class - removeItems method called from a button view object;

```
private void removeItems() {
    final SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
    //final long[] checkedItemIds = listView.getCheckedItemIds();
    final int checkedItemsCount = checkedItems.size();

    Log.d("drp", "Adapter Count is: " + Integer.toString(mMyListViewAdapter.getCount()));
    if (checkedItems != null) {
        for (int i = checkedItemsCount-1; i >= 0 ; --i) {
            // This tells us the item position we are looking at
            // --
            final int position = checkedItems.keyAt(i);
            // This tells us the item status at the above position
            // --
            final boolean isChecked = checkedItems.valueAt(i);

            if (isChecked) {
                Item item = mMyListViewAdapter.getItem(position);
                Log.d("drp", "removing : " + Integer.toString(position) + " of " +Integer.toString(checkedItemsCount) + "-" + Integer.toString(i) + " - Title: " + mMyListViewAdapter.getItem(position).getTitle());
                mMyListViewAdapter.remove(item);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter Class;

```
public class MyListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>  implements OnItemClickListener{

private LayoutInflater mInflator;

/**
 * This is my view holder for getView method so don't need to call
 * findViewById all the time which results in speed increase
 */
static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView txtTitle;
    public TextView txtDescription;
    public TextView txtSessionCount;
    public ImageView listThumbnailImage;
    public ImageView listStatusIndicatorImage;
    public InertCheckBox Checkbox;
}

/**
 * Constructor from a list of items
 */
public MyListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
    super(context, 0, items);
    mInflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // This is how you would determine if this particular item is checked
    // when the view gets created
    // --
    final ListView lv = (ListView) parent;
    final boolean isChecked = lv.isItemChecked(position);
    final int selectionMode = lv.getChoiceMode();

    // The item we want to get the view for
    // --
    Item item = getItem(position);

    // Re-use the view if possible (recycle)
    // --
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.txtSessionCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.session_count);
        holder.listThumbnailImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        holder.listStatusIndicatorImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        holder.Checkbox = (InertCheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inertCheckBox);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.txtDescription.setText(item.getDescription());
    holder.txtSessionCount.setText(item.getSessionCount());
    holder.listThumbnailImage.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) item.getThumbnailImage());        
    switch (selectionMode) {
    case ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE:
        holder.Checkbox.setVisibility(InertCheckBox.GONE);
        holder.listStatusIndicatorImage.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        holder.listStatusIndicatorImage.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) item.getListIndicatorImage());
        break;
    //case ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE: case ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE:
    default:
        holder.listStatusIndicatorImage.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
        holder.Checkbox.setVisibility(InertCheckBox.VISIBLE);
        holder.Checkbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox);
        holder.Checkbox.setChecked(isChecked);
        break;
    }           


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return getItem(position).getId();
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}
```

And Item Class - first half;

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {

private long id;
private String title;
private String description;
private String session_count;
private Bitmap listImage;
private Bitmap statusImage;

public Item(long id, String title, String description, String session_count, Bitmap listImage, Bitmap statusImage) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.session_count = session_count;
    this.listImage = listImage;
    this.statusImage = statusImage;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
```

Here is visual of my debug log tracking item removals

```
07-23 22:59:14.910: D/drp(19104): Adapter Count is: 51
07-23 22:59:14.910: D/drp(19104): removing : 50 of 4-3 - Title: Test 50 - testing
07-23 22:59:14.910: D/drp(19104): removing : 49 of 4-2 - Title: Test 49 - testing
07-23 22:59:14.910: D/drp(19104): removing : 48 of 4-1 - Title: Test 48 - testing
```

Again if I comment out the "mMyListViewAdapter.remove(item);" line in MainActivity not crashes and log seems to indicated its working as expected.  Can anyone see my error that results in my Index Out Of Bounds Exception?

Also I am using SDK 4.0.4 API 15.

Many Thanks,

Paul.

Addition - full log output

```
        07-25 00:21:53.235: D/AbsListView(25952): Get MotionRecognitionManager
        07-25 00:21:53.270: D/dalvikvm(25952): GC_CONCURRENT freed 89K, 3% free 13027K/13383K, paused 1ms+2ms
        07-25 00:21:53.430: D/dalvikvm(25952): GC_CONCURRENT freed 207K, 4% free 13232K/13703K, paused 3ms+2ms
        07-25 00:21:53.630: D/CLIPBOARD(25952): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
        07-25 00:21:54.930: D/dalvikvm(25952): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 189K, 4% free 13331K/13767K, paused 10ms
        07-25 00:21:54.930: I/dalvikvm-heap(25952): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.610MB for 408976-byte allocation
        07-25 00:21:54.940: D/dalvikvm(25952): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 4% free 13724K/14215K, paused 9ms
        07-25 00:21:54.950: D/dalvikvm(25952): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 4% free 13724K/14215K, paused 9ms
        07-25 00:21:54.950: I/dalvikvm-heap(25952): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.994MB for 408976-byte allocation
        07-25 00:21:54.960: D/dalvikvm(25952): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 4% free 14124K/14663K, paused 9ms
        07-25 00:21:54.970: D/dalvikvm(25952): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 4% free 14124K/14663K, paused 9ms
        07-25 00:21:54.975: I/dalvikvm-heap(25952): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.384MB for 408976-byte allocation
        07-25 00:21:54.995: D/dalvikvm(25952): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 14523K/15111K, paused 1ms+1ms
        07-25 00:21:55.005: D/dalvikvm(25952): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 4% free 14523K/15111K, paused 9ms
        07-25 00:21:55.005: I/dalvikvm-heap(25952): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.774MB for 408976-byte allocation
        07-25 00:21:55.020: D/dalvikvm(25952): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 5% free 14923K/15559K, paused 9ms
        07-25 00:21:55.030: D/dalvikvm(25952): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 14923K/15559K, paused 9ms
        07-25 00:21:55.030: I/dalvikvm-heap(25952): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.165MB for 408976-byte allocation
        07-25 00:21:55.040: D/dalvikvm(25952): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 5% free 15322K/16007K, paused 10ms
        07-25 00:21:55.055: D/dalvikvm(25952): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 5% free 15722K/16455K, paused 9ms
        07-25 00:21:55.110: D/dalvikvm(25952): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 157K, 5% free 16145K/16903K, paused 9ms
        07-25 00:21:56.565: E/SKIA(25952): FimgApiStretch:stretch failed
        07-25 00:21:56.690: E/SKIA(25952): FimgApiStretch:stretch failed
        07-25 00:21:56.710: E/SKIA(25952): FimgApiStretch:stretch failed
        07-25 00:22:00.545: D/drp(25952): Adapter Count is: 51
        07-25 00:22:00.545: D/drp(25952): removing : 49 of 2-2 - Title: Test 49 - testing
        07-25 00:22:00.545: D/drp(25952): removing : 48 of 2-1 - Title: Test 48 - testing
        07-25 00:22:00.545: D/drp(25952): removing : 47 of 2-0 - Title: Test 47 - testing
        07-25 00:22:00.550: D/AndroidRuntime(25952): Shutting down VM
        07-25 00:22:00.550: W/dalvikvm(25952): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c6f1f8)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 48, size is 48
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at au.drp.mylistview.MyListViewAdapter.getItemId(MyListViewAdapter.java:107)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.widget.AbsListView.confirmCheckedPositionsById(AbsListView.java:5956)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.widget.AbsListView.handleDataChanged(AbsListView.java:5999)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1535)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2254)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11467)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4237)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11467)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4237)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11467)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4237)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1644)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1502)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1415)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11467)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4237)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11467)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4237)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2678)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
        07-25 00:22:00.560: E/AndroidRuntime(25952):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
```

Comment: follow this tutorial may help you http://www.quicktips.in/how-to-create-multi-select-listview-android-with-custom-adapter/

Comment: Thanks for selectionMode = lv.getChoiceMode(). I looked for this.

Answer (score 4):

There appears to be a bug in [`AbsListView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java) that causes this issue. It can happen with any subclass of `AbsListView`, including `ListView` and `GridView`.

In single- and multi-choice mode, the `ListView`  responds to a `notifyDataSetChanged()` call on its adapter by verifying the set of checked items in `confirmCheckedPositionsById()`. Since the selected item(s) have already been deleted from the dataset at that point, the adapter will throw an exception. Notably, this issue only occurs if the adapter's `hasStableIds()` method returns `true`.

Loosely speaking, this is the relevant path:

1. You select one or more items in the ListView
2. The `ListView` updates its list of selected items
3. You click the delete button
4. The item(s) are removed from your dataset
5. You call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter, and it notifies its observers that the dataset has changed. The `ListView` is one of those observers.
6. Next time the `ListView` is redrawn, it sees the adapter's notification and calls `handleDataChanged()`. At this point, the `ListView` still thinks that our now-deleted items are selected *and in the dataset*.
7. The `handleDataChanged()` method calls `confirmCheckedPositionsById()`, which in turn tries to call `getItemId()` on the adapter using a stale position. If the deleted item happens to be near the end of the list, this position is likely to be out of bounds for the array, and the adapter will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Two possible workarounds are as follows:

- Create a new adapter every time the dataset changes, as noted in other answers. This has the unfortunate effect of losing the current scroll position unless it's saved and restored manually.
- Clear the selected items by calling `clearChoices()` on the `ListView` (or `GridView`) before you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter. The selected items will be deleted anyhow, so losing the current selection state is unlikely to be a problem. This method will preserve the scroll position and should prevent flickering while the list is being updated.

Comment: acj, you are correct there is a bug when confirmCheckPositionsByid() is called on a stale position. However, I found that if I call clearChoices() then ActionMode#finish fails to exit multi-select mode.

Comment: @PeterTran Interesting. Calling `clearChoices()` and then `ActionMode#finish()` to exit multi-select mode has worked for me. (My work has been on 4.0+.) Please post again if you find a workaround.

Comment: clearChoices！！！IS OK！！！BUT DONNOT FORGET setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);FOLLOW!

Answer (score 4):

The bug in `confirmCheckedPositionsById` (bullet #7 in acj's answer) causes `getItemId` to get called on a stale position. However, it will get called again with the correct position to refresh the layout. When I ran into this problem I updated the custom Adapter's `getItemId` like so

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position < getCount() ? getItem(position).getId() : -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for me! I don't know, but we have 2015 and there is still the bug in `confirmCheckedPositionsById`.

Comment: hi, 2015!! it's now 2021 and I'm still facing this same bug :@

Answer (score 3):

Ok I solved the issue!!! YAY!

What I had to do to prevent the IndexOutOFBounds Exception was to reset the list view adapter so to refresh the list view contents.  So the magic line was

```
 listView.setAdapter(mMyListViewAdapter);
```

However I believe this is not the best practise to use when working with a list view and its better to update the content of the adapter that the list view is attached to.  But I not quite sure how to go about that?

Anyway he is my updated remove method code.

```
private void removeItems() {
    final SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

    if (checkedItems != null) {
        final int checkedItemsCount = checkedItems.size();

        // Lets get the position of the view to scroll to before the first checked 
        // item to restore scroll position
        //          
        int topPosition = checkedItems.keyAt(0) - 1;            

        listView.setAdapter(null);
        for (int i = checkedItemsCount - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            // This tells us the item position we are looking at
            // --
            final int position = checkedItems.keyAt(i);

            // This tells us the item status at the above position
            // --
            final boolean isChecked = checkedItems.valueAt(i);
            if (isChecked) {
                Item item = mMyListViewAdapter.getItem(position);
                mMyListViewAdapter.remove(item);
                //mMyListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }               
        }
        listView.setAdapter(mMyListViewAdapter);
        //if topPosition is -1 then item zero is positioned by default.
        listView.setSelection(topPosition);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a documented bug, please vote for it:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=64596

My use case is the ListView configured as ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, I tried @Peter Tran's suggestion without any luck. Here is the workaround that is successful for me:

```
    myAdapter.deleteRow(listView.getCheckedItemPosition());
    int checkedIndex = listView.getCheckedItemPosition();
    System.out.println("checkedIndex="+checkedIndex);

    int count=myAdapter.getCount();
    if (checkedIndex==count) listView.setItemChecked(count-1, true);
```

My test is to manually select the last item on the list(count-1). I omitted the handling for count==0 case but that will most likely be needed. I observed that println() always prints the index of the deleted row. myAdapter.deleteRow() notifies of data change to listeners which says to me ListView isn't properly updating it's checked indices. I've tried this code with hasStableIds() returning both true and false from the custom adapter with the same results.

Comment: unfortunately the bug ticket got closed because it was open too long without any attention from Google :( otherwise I would have voted for it. it's 2021 and I'm still facing this issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Filter using AlertDialog.Builder fully customized :-

```
((TextView) TabBarWithCustomStack.vPublic.findViewById(R.id.tv_edit)) .setVisibility(View.GONE);
    class DialogSelectionClickHandler implements
            DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked,
                boolean selected) {
            Log.i("ME", hosts.toArray()[clicked] + " selected: " + selected);
        }
    }

    class DialogButtonClickHandler implements
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked) {
            switch (clicked) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                filteredList.clear();
                statusesSelected.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < statusesStringArray.length; i++) {
                    // Log.i( "ME", statuses.toArray()[ i ] + " selected: "
                    // + isSelectedStatuses[i] );

                    if (isSelectedStatuses[i] == true) {

                        if (statuses.get(i).toString()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("Accepted")) {
                            statusesSelected.add("1");
                        } else if (statuses.get(i).toString()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("Rejected")) {
                            statusesSelected.add("2");
                        } else if (statuses.get(i).toString()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("Pending")) {
                            statusesSelected.add("3");
                        }

                    }
                    isSelectedStatuses[i] = false;
                }

                Calendar currentCalender = Calendar.getInstance(Locale
                        .getDefault());

                Date currentDate = new Date(
                        currentCalender.getTimeInMillis());

                if (listSelected == 0) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < arr_BLID.size(); j++) {
                        if (Helper.stringToDate(
                                arr_BLID.get(j).getStart_ts().toString(),
                                Helper.SERVER_FORMAT).after(currentDate)) {
                            if (statusesSelected.contains(arr_BLID.get(j)
                                    .getStatus())) {
                                filteredList.add(arr_BLID.get(j));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    for (int j = 0; j < arr_BLID.size(); j++) {
                        if (currentDate.after(Helper.stringToDate(arr_BLID
                                .get(j).getStart_ts().toString(),
                                Helper.SERVER_FORMAT))) {
                            if (statusesSelected.contains(arr_BLID.get(j)
                                    .getStatus())) {
                                filteredList.add(arr_BLID.get(j));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

                lvBeeps.setAdapter(new EventsAdapter(ctx));

                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE: {

                currentCalender = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());

                currentDate = new Date(currentCalender.getTimeInMillis());

                if (listSelected == 0) {

                    filteredList.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr_BLID.size(); i++) {
                        if (Helper.stringToDate(
                                arr_BLID.get(i).getStart_ts().toString(),
                                Helper.SERVER_FORMAT).after(currentDate)) {
                            filteredList.add(arr_BLID.get(i));
                        }

                        if (i < isSelectedStatuses.length) {
                            isSelectedStatuses[i] = false;
                        } else {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    lvBeeps.setAdapter(new EventsAdapter(ctx));
                } else {

                    filteredList.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr_BLID.size(); i++) {
                        if (currentDate.after(Helper.stringToDate(arr_BLID
                                .get(i).getStart_ts().toString(),
                                Helper.SERVER_FORMAT))) {
                            filteredList.add(arr_BLID.get(i));
                        }

                        if (i < isSelectedStatuses.length) {
                            isSelectedStatuses[i] = false;
                        } else {
                            continue;
                        }

                    }

                    lvBeeps.setAdapter(new EventsAdapter(ctx));

                }
            }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    btnHost = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnHost);
    btnHost.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // ((TextView)((RelativeLayout)getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.event_filter_title,
            // null)).findViewById(R.id.tvDialogTitle)).setText("Hosts");

            // Log.d( "Dialog object",
            // " static made dialog in checkbox--> "+((TextView)((RelativeLayout)getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.event_filter_title,
            // null)).findViewById(R.id.tvDialogTitle)).getText());

            final LayoutInflater inflater123 = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            final View view123 = inflater123.inflate(
                    R.layout.event_filter_title, null);

            // Log.d( "Dialog object",
            // " static made dialog in view123--> "+view123);
            //
            // Log.d( "Dialog object",
            // " static made dialog in checkbox--> "+((CheckBox)view123.findViewById(R.id.cbSelectAll)));
            //
            // Log.d( "Dialog object",
            // " static made dialog in checkbox--> "+((CheckBox)inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_filter_title,
            // (ViewGroup) ((AlertDialog)
            // BeepsFragment.dialog).getCurrentFocus(),
            // true).findViewById(R.id.cbSelectAll)));
            //
            // Log.d( "Dialog object",
            // " static made dialog in checkbox--> "+((CheckBox)(((RelativeLayout)getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.event_filter_title,
            // null)).findViewById(R.id.cbSelectAll))));
            hostsDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setCustomTitle(/*
                                     * Html.fromHtml(
                                     * "<b><font color=\"purple\">  Host</font></b>"
                                     * )
                                     */view123)
                    .setIcon(
                            getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(
                                    R.drawable.add_host))
                    .setMultiChoiceItems(hostsStringArray, isSelectedHosts,
                            new OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                                // android.content.DialogInterface.OnShowListener
                                // ocl = new
                                // DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                                //
                                // @Override
                                // public void onShow(DialogInterface
                                // dialog) {
                                // // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // BeepsFragment.dialog = dialog;
                                // }
                                // };

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int clicked, boolean selected) {

                                    boolean all = true;
                                    Log.i("ME", hosts.toArray()[clicked]
                                            + " selected: " + selected);

                                    // for (int i = 0; i <
                                    // isSelectedHosts.length; i++ ){
                                    //
                                    // if(isSelectedHosts[i]==true){
                                    // all = true;
                                    // }else{
                                    // all = false;
                                    // }
                                    // }
                                    //
                                    // Log.i( "ME", all + " selected:--- "
                                    // +((CheckBox)view123.findViewById(R.id.cbSelectAll)));
                                    //
                                    // if(all = true){
                                    // ((CheckBox)view123.findViewById(R.id.cbSelectAll)).setChecked(true);
                                    // }else{
                                    // ((CheckBox)view123.findViewById(R.id.cbSelectAll)).setChecked(false);
                                    // }

                                    Log.d("Dialog object",
                                            " static made dialog --> "
                                                    + BeepsFragment.dialog
                                                    + " from parameter dialog --> "
                                                    + dialog);

                                }

                            })
                    .setPositiveButton(
                            Html.fromHtml("<b><font color=\"purple\">Apply Filter</font></b>"),
                            new DialogButtonClickHandler() {

                                // android.content.DialogInterface.OnShowListener
                                // ocl = new
                                // DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                                //
                                // @Override
                                // public void onShow(DialogInterface
                                // dialog) {
                                // // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // BeepsFragment.dialog = dialog;
                                // }
                                // };

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int clicked) {
                                    switch (clicked) {
                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:

                                        filteredList.clear();
                                        hostsSelected.clear();

                                        for (int i = 0; i < hostsStringArray.length; i++) {
                                            Log.i("ME",
                                                    hosts.toArray()[i]
                                                            + " selected: "
                                                            + isSelectedHosts[i]
                                                            + "\n\n\t hostStringArray-->"
                                                            + hostsStringArray[i]);

                                            if (isSelectedHosts[i] == true) {

                                                hostsSelected.add(hosts
                                                        .get(i));
                                                isSelectedHosts[i] = false;
                                            }
                                            // isSelectedHosts[i] = false;
                                        }

                                        Calendar currentCalender = Calendar
                                                .getInstance(Locale
                                                        .getDefault());

                                        Date currentDate = new Date(
                                                currentCalender
                                                        .getTimeInMillis());

                                        if (listSelected == 0) {
                                            for (int j = 0; j < arr_BLID
                                                    .size(); j++) {
                                                if (Helper
                                                        .stringToDate(
                                                                arr_BLID.get(
                                                                        j)
                                                                        .getStart_ts()
                                                                        .toString(),
                                                                Helper.SERVER_FORMAT)
                                                        .after(currentDate)) {
                                                    if (hostsSelected
                                                            .contains(arr_BLID
                                                                    .get(j)
                                                                    .getHost_name())) {
                                                        filteredList
                                                                .add(arr_BLID
                                                                        .get(j));
                                                    }
                                                    if (hostsSelected
                                                            .contains("Me"))
                                                        if (BeepApplication
                                                                .getSelfId() == arr_BLID
                                                                .get(j)
                                                                .getHost_id())
                                                            filteredList
                                                                    .add(arr_BLID
                                                                            .get(j));
                                                }
                                            }

                                        } else {
                                            for (int j = 0; j < arr_BLID
                                                    .size(); j++) {
                                                if (currentDate.after(Helper
                                                        .stringToDate(
                                                                arr_BLID.get(
                                                                        j)
                                                                        .getStart_ts()
                                                                        .toString(),
                                                                Helper.SERVER_FORMAT))) {
                                                    if (hostsSelected
                                                            .contains(arr_BLID
                                                                    .get(j)
                                                                    .getHost_name())) {
                                                        filteredList
                                                                .add(arr_BLID
                                                                        .get(j));
                                                    }
                                                    if (hostsSelected
                                                            .contains("Me"))
                                                        if (BeepApplication
                                                                .getSelfId() == arr_BLID
                                                                .get(j)
                                                                .getHost_id())
                                                            filteredList
                                                                    .add(arr_BLID
                                                                            .get(j));
                                                }
                                            }

                                        }
                                        lvBeeps.setAdapter(new EventsAdapter(
                                                ctx));
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(
                            Html.fromHtml("<b><font color=\"purple\">Remove Filter</font></b>"),
                            new DialogButtonClickHandler() {

                                public void onClick(
                                        final DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int clicked) {

                                    Calendar currentCalender = Calendar
                                            .getInstance(Locale
                                                    .getDefault());

                                    Date currentDate = new Date(
                                            currentCalender
                                                    .getTimeInMillis());

                                    if (listSelected == 0) {

                                        filteredList.clear();
                                        for (int i = 0; i < arr_BLID.size(); i++) {
                                            if (Helper.stringToDate(
                                                    arr_BLID.get(i)
                                                            .getStart_ts()
                                                            .toString(),
                                                    Helper.SERVER_FORMAT)
                                                    .after(currentDate)) {
                                                filteredList.add(arr_BLID
                                                        .get(i));
                                                if (i < isSelectedHosts.length) {
                                                    isSelectedHosts[i] = false;
                                                } else {
                                                    continue;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                        lvBeeps.setAdapter(new EventsAdapter(
                                                ctx));
                                    } else {

                                        filteredList.clear();
                                        for (int i = 0; i < arr_BLID.size(); i++) {
                                            if (currentDate.after(Helper
                                                    .stringToDate(
                                                            arr_BLID.get(i)
                                                                    .getStart_ts()
                                                                    .toString(),
                                                            Helper.SERVER_FORMAT))) {
                                                filteredList.add(arr_BLID
                                                        .get(i));
                                                if (i < isSelectedHosts.length) {
                                                    isSelectedHosts[i] = false;
                                                } else {
                                                    continue;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                        lvBeeps.setAdapter(new EventsAdapter(
                                                ctx));

                                    }
                                }
                            });

            final AlertDialog dlg = hostsDialog.create();

            dlg.show();

            ((TextView) view123.findViewById(R.id.tvDialogTitle))
                    .setText("Hosts");

            ((CheckBox) view123.findViewById(R.id.cbSelectAll))
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(
                                CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            if (isChecked == true) {

                                ListView list = dlg.getListView();
                                for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {

                                    isSelectedHosts[i] = true;
                                    list.setItemChecked(i, true);

                                }

                            }

                            else if (isChecked == false) {

                                ListView list = dlg.getListView();
                                for (int j = 0; j < list.getCount(); j++) {

                                    isSelectedHosts[j] = false;
                                    list.setItemChecked(j, false);
                                }
                                // }
                            }

                        }
                    });

        }
    });

    btnStatus = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStatus);
    btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater inflater123 = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view123 = inflater123.inflate(R.layout.event_filter_title,
                    null);

            statusDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setIcon(
                            getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(
                                    R.drawable.add_host))
                    .setCustomTitle(/*
                                     * Html.fromHtml(
                                     * "<b><font color=\"purple\">  Status</font></b>"
                                     * )
                                     */view123)
                    .setIcon(
                            getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(
                                    R.drawable.add_host))
                    .setMultiChoiceItems(statusesStringArray,
                            isSelectedStatuses,
                            new DialogSelectionClickHandler())
                    .setPositiveButton(
                            Html.fromHtml("<b><font color=\"purple\">Apply Filter</font></b>"),
                            new DialogButtonClickHandler() {

                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(
                            Html.fromHtml("<b><font color=\"purple\">Remove Filter</font></b>"),
                            new DialogButtonClickHandler());

            final AlertDialog dlg = statusDialog.create();

            dlg.show();

            ((TextView) view123.findViewById(R.id.tvDialogTitle))
                    .setText("Status");
            ((CheckBox) view123.findViewById(R.id.cbSelectAll))
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(
                                CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            if (isChecked == true) {

                                ListView list = dlg.getListView();
                                for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {

                                    isSelectedStatuses[i] = true;
                                    list.setItemChecked(i, true);

                                }

                            }

                            else if (isChecked == false) {

                                ListView list = dlg.getListView();
                                for (int j = 0; j < list.getCount(); j++) {

                                    isSelectedStatuses[j] = false;
                                    list.setItemChecked(j, false);
                                }
                                // }
                            }

                        }
                    });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit as :

```
for (int i = checkedItemsCount-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                                          ^^^^^
```

**INSTED OF**

```
for (int i = checkedItemsCount-1; i >= 0 ; --i) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately I still have the same Index Out Of Bounds Exception. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Post your whole Log-Cat displaying Error.

Comment: Do you have file ArrayList.java?? If yes, What is code at Line No: 251 of that file??

Comment: It's not a file I coded. Assume it's linked at compile time from sdk. I can take closer look when in front of pc.

Comment: The code change in this answer should make no difference at all. A preincrement vs. postincrement only matters if the value of the `i--` or `--i` expression is being used, which it isn't when it's the third part of a for loop.